# How to compute the gradient of $\Vert \mid{Ax}\mid^2 -b \Vert_2^2$?

Tags: vector-analysis

$$f(\bf{x}) = \Vert \mid{Ax}\mid^2 -b \Vert_2^2
=(\mid{Ax}\mid^2 -b)^T(\mid{Ax}\mid^2 -b ) $$
Then, gradient is,
$$\frac{\partial f(\bf{x})}{\partial \bf{x}}= 2(\mid{\bf{Ax}}\mid^2 -\bf{b})^T\frac{\partial (\mid{Ax}\mid^2 -b ) }{\partial \bf{x}} $$

where $\mid{\bf{Ax}}\mid^2$ is element by element absolute value squared.

How do I proceed after this?

P.S $A$ ,$x$ and $b$ are complex-valued matrix and vectors respectively

Comment: What is it supposed to mean? $|Ax|^2$ supposed to be element by element absolute value squared or something else?

Comment: $\Vert$ is usually norm, $\vert$ absolute value or complex modulus, etc. my guess an l2 norm of an absolute value squared minus another value.

Comment: Yes it is an  element by element absolute value squared .

Comment: Maybe you can reformulate it somehow? Do matrices or vectors have complex or real valued elements?

Comment: @mathreadler it is all complex valued.